# Minimum Number of Drinks required to Satisfy all Customomer

Tags: algorithm, hashmap, greedy

I have found this Question in Online Coding Comp . And I was not able to solve it Efficiently .
Question :
In bar there are N customers and they can like at most M Drinks. And a customer is satisfied, If he gets at least one drink of his choice.  We need to find the Minimum no of drink to be prepared to satisfy all the Customers . Below Is an Example

```
N = 3 # No of Customer 
M = 3 (Maximum Drinks available )
customer 1 : [ 2,1,3]
customer 2 : [1,1]
customer 3 : [2,2,3]
```

Note : A customer can like same drink multiple times also .
Answer : Minimum No of Drinks Required is 2 
Explanation : If we prepare **Drink Number 1 and 2** then All three customer can be satisfied .

My Solutions :
I created a hashMap of drinks as key and Customer value

```
Drink  : Customer
 1 : [1 ,2]
 2 : [1,3]
 3 : [1,3]
```

1. And the I would pick up the largest List of values (Since all the customers will be unique) from Hashmap.

All are equal in this case, so I will pick Drink 1's values [1,2]

```
globalList = [1,2]
noOfDrinksRequired = 1
```

2. And now I will find Inter Section with All other list , whichever intersection is largest I will add it to Global List `(globalList)` and  increment the no of drinks required `(noOfDrinksRequired)` By 1 . And also keep track of number of element in List (" Number of Customer "). If the list length is equals to number of customer, then I quit .

   globalList = globalList ∩ [1,3] # Drink 2's or 3's value
     Now the golbalList = [1,2,3]
     And noOfDrinksRequired += 1
     Since the golbalList.length == N # no of Customer 3
     If not repeat step 2

I know this is not very optimize solution ( Space complexity m*n and time complexity not sure of ) . Can any one tell me the Optimize solution to this problem . Also I am not sure if my solution will work 100% .

Comment: Please read on NP-complete problems. Yours is a set-cover problem. In particular this means that if you think you have an O(n^2) algorithm you probably need to think again.

Comment: Well I did not calculated it mathematically . it was approximate guess , and could be wrong also .

Comment: Well it is wrong. If you want an approximate solution then I guess your solution is the same as the [greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Greedy_algorithm) though it's hard to tell for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic Set cover problem -- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem

It is in fact one of Karp's 21 NP-complete problems. There are approximate and greedy solutions to this.

Comment: It would be nice to mention that the formulation of this problem as a set cover is to take the sets of customers who like a particular drink and the universe the set of all customers. If you apply set cover literally to the sets given in the question you'll get a set of customers who between them like all the drinks.